# Select value based on role

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following results from a temp table.
 
Please Note : The data below is just a sample so I don't need a hardcoded query, I need a query which works for all kinds of data.

Value = 1 means the User has the role and 0 means the user has no role.
Like row one Testing 1 has Role A but not Role D.

I need a query for the below cases.

Case # 1  when `Role ID = ( A,B,C,D )` 
I only need the user/s which have atleast one role assigned.
I should get back User Testing 1, Testing 2 and Testing 3. Testing 4 wont be coming as no role has been assigned to it.

Case # 2 When `Role ID = ( A,B,C,D )` .
I only need the user/s which have all the roles assigned to a it.
I should get User Testing2 with 4 rows.

> username  Value   Role ID
>   Testing1    1 A
>   Testing1    1 B
>   Testing1    1 C
>   Testing1    0 D
>   Testing2    1     A
>   Testing2    1 B
>   Testing2    1 C
>   Testing2    1 D
>   Testing3    1 A
>   Testing3    1 B
>   Testing3    1 C
>   Testing3    0 D
>   Testing4    0 A
>   Testing4    0 B
>   Testing4    0 C
>   Testing4    0 D

Comment: *what - apparently I haven't tried checked typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE # 1 (*which have atleast one role assigned*)

```
SELECT b.*
FROM   
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT [username], Value
      FROM tableName
      WHERE value = 1
    ) a
      INNER JOIN TableName b
        ON a.username = b.username
WHERE  a.value = 1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb29f/6)

CASE # 2 (*which have all the roles assigned to a it*)

```
SELECT username
FROM tableName
WHERE RoleID IN ('A','B','C','D')
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT roleID) = 4
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b915/1)

Comment: Thanks man but for case # 1 i need to get username with all 4 rows. Testing 1 with all 4 roles . The total number of rows returned should be 12

Comment: you said `Testing 4 wont be coming as no role has been assigned to it.`

Comment: yes i agree but your query will only return 3 rows ... not 12 rows

Comment: i need to get username , value and roleid. So the total rows should be 12

Comment: @Ally is this what you want? [Click for demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b915/5)

Comment: @John you know the answer isn't correct, right? [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb29f/1/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb29f/1/0) User 1 is missing

Comment: @Richard ... do you have an answer for me ? yes you are right. User 1 should have come ....

Comment: [this is an updated answer (click here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb29f/5). @RichardTheKiwi is it ok now?

Comment: how about case 2 ... need a generic query like case 1. thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get your final result (all records for the user), take one of the queries (CASE X) below and JOIN it back to the full table, e.g. for CASE 1:

```
  select t.*
    from (
          select username
            from tbl
           where value = 1
        group by username) g
    join tbl t on t.username = g.username
order by t.username, t.roleid
```

CASE 1: Users who have at least one role

```
  select username
    from tbl
   where value = 1
group by username
```

CASE 2: Users who have ALL roles (number of roles unknown)

```
  select username
    from tbl
   where value = 1
group by username
  having count(distinct roleid) = (select count(distinct roleid) from tbl)
```

CASE 2: Users who have ALL roles (number of roles known in advance, e.g. A,B,C,D => 4)

```
  select username
    from tbl
   where value = 1
group by username
  having count(distinct roleid) = 4
```